# Docker compose build relative path

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, build, docker-compose

```
creditcard-monk:
 build:
  context: ./creditcard
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  args:
    JAR_FILE: target/creditcard-1.0.0.jar
```

Docker compose version 3.0. The jar_file argument is used to copy the jar-file to spring-boot jar under docker container

I get the error `failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder347176151/target/creditcard-1.0.0.jar: no such file or directory`

i thought the mentioning of context ,will read jar from target folder .but it seems docker-compose is not reading the file from context specified

Please help.
Note:- the docker file is simple, built from alpine-java-8 and a copy command to copy jar to container to start spring boot app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    creditcard-monk:
     build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        JAR_FILE: target/creditcard-1.0.0.jar
```

or

```
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=target/creditcard-1.0.0.jar
```

both commands worked now. But the second command worked in most cases and never failed.

As the docker is already running inside the folder

Answer (score 0):

Your current code assumes the following path exists:

```
./creditcard/target/creditcard-1.0.0.jar
```

The JAR_FILE path will be inside the path you specified for context. Double check what the path should be and update your context and JAR_FILE argument accordingly.

Comment: sorry for late reply.. no it wasn't the case, the  file is present there. But docker while building is lookign to its temp directory where it build s the docker pkg.
my directory structure is as follows `` monk--> creditcard (folder)
                                                                           docker-compose `` and yes the target is present inside credit card folder

Comment: the issue is resolved based on your direction ..but not mentioning the folder after the current directory.. so givign the hands up
  jobmanager:
    build:
      context: ./
      args: 
        JAR_FILE: target/creditcard-1.0.0.jar